# Implementing getStreamFromPOtherSource() to handle Exceptions

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I'm Using [Android Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in my news app i'm currently working on. I'm using [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/) to fetch news. After parsing the JSON from the website. I populate a list view using a custom adapter and universal image loader is used to get the images in background. But for some pictures `UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [null].You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))` exception is displayed.

I think in some images the URI is not in the format of Library expecting.

So my question is how do i fill the image's position which gave me the error from a picture that i have in the Drawable Folder. (404 picture indicating the image could not be downloaded)

i found where i should put the code.

`protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [%s]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))", new Object[]{imageUri}));
    }`

I need to know what kind of code i should put here to put a 404 image from my drawable file if the image is not downloadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro.. you can use [Piccasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) image library for android. It can solve your issue.

Sample code:

```
if(!image.equals("default")){


                Picasso.with(Profile.this).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.default).into(mDisplayImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(Profile.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default).into(mDisplayImage);

                    }
                });
```

}

Here it can replace the default (i.e) 404 found image while Error condition

And small suggesstion that, you can use [Easy News](https://github.com/Sivakumar00/EasyNews) Library for simple retrieval of news from NewsAPI. Here we don't need to parse the JSON. It gives the data by single method call